# How do I store value in my database in a dynamic dropdown list?

Tags: php, html, sql

**This is a dynamic dropdown in PHP/mySQL.**
I want to store the name in the database server but the  tag outputs the integer value.

If i change the code from `<option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">` to `<option value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>">` It shows my_sqli_fetch_array expects parameter 1 error.

My objective being to store the corresponding $row["name"] that is being displayed on the dropdown instead of $row["id"].

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "");
mysqli_select_db($link,"loginsystem");

?>

<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Select Assembly Line</td>
<td><select id ="assemblylinedd" onChange="change_assemblyline()">
<option>Select</option>

<?php
$i=1;
$res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM assemblyline");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($count >0){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>
}

<?php $i++;} }else{
echo "No record Found !";
} ?>

</select></td>
</tr>
```

Scripting code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_assemblyline()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?assemblyline="+document.getElementById("assemblylinedd").value, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("devices").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
```

This is my ajax.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "");
mysqli_select_db($link,"loginsystem");

$assemblyline = isset($_GET['assemblyline']) ? $_GET['assemblyline'] : '';
$devices = isset($_GET['devices']) ? $_GET['devices'] : '';


if($assemblyline!="")
{   

    $res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE devices_id=$assemblyline");
    echo "<select id='devicesdd' onchange='change_devices()'>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))

    {

    echo "<option value='$row[id]'>";echo $row["name"]; echo "</option>";

    }
    echo "</select>";

}
```

Please do ignore onchange_devices() as it follows the same for next consecutive dropdown.

Comment: It is not advisable to use unquoted keys (`$row[id]`).

Comment: **Warning!** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @Script47 - If you put the array in a double quoted string (without wrapping it in `{}`), you _have_ to have the keys unquoted. It's either `value='$row[id]'` or `value='{$row['id']}'`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you can very easily close the double quotes and do the output like that (`value='" . $row["id"] . "'`), I'm personally not too fond of using it as the OP has because it can cause confusion. However, as my comment mentioned, 'advisable'.

Comment: @Script47 - _"'I'm personally not too fond of using it as the OP"_ is not the same as _"It is not advisable"_. I've honestly never seen that advice. Personally, I prefer `{$row['id']}` instead of closing the quotes. In my opinion, it's more readable.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think you've misunderstand the meaning of '*advisable*', my original comment is just that, advice. As it was coming from me, it was going to be my opinion (my fondness). At the end of the day, each to their own.

Comment: @Script47 - That's fair enough. I actually read it as it's generally advisable. It might just be me, since English isn't my first language, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Though, its your requirement to save device name in DB, it is advised to save numeric id.

Reason: Name may change, but, id will persist.

If say your device id:name is `99 : iPhone 6` and you save in DB: `iPhone 6`, later the name gets changed to `iPhone6`.

In this scenario if you search records with name `iPhone6`, clearly, your above record will not show.

If you save numeric id, it will show irrespective of name change.

Coming back to your question:

I cannot write code here. But a pseudo code logic will help (hope so):

1. Take a hidden field `device_name`.
2. On change of drop down, with `jQuery`, assign value to hidden field.
3. `$("#assemblylinedd option:selected").text();`
4. Now, after submit, you will get `device_name` in hidden field.
5. `$devices = isset($_GET['device_name']) ? $_GET['device_name'] : '';`

Save this to DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "");
mysqli_select_db($link, "loginsystem");

$assemblyline = isset($_GET['assemblyline']) ? $_GET['assemblyline'] : '';
$devices = isset($_GET['devices']) ? $_GET['devices'] : '';


if(!empty(trim($assemblyline)))
{   
    $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE devices_id = '$assemblyline'");

    echo "<select id='devicesdd' onchange='change_devices()'>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {

        echo "<option value='" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row["name"] . "</option>";

    }

    echo "</select>";
}
```

- I've added a proper empty check instead of your `!= ""`, which didn't previously prevent a single space from being passed.
- I've quoted your query value, I would definitely use prepared statements instead of passing values directly.
- I've quoted your `$row[id]`.
- I've concatenated your string correctly.

**Note:** It would be preferable to return a JSON array object with the IDs and the names instead of outputting HTML via the AJAX, it would make your code-base much cleaner and adaptable in the future.

**Reading Material**

[`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

[`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)